# PCS resource ipaddr2 failed to start with exitreason='[findif] failed'

Tags: pacemaker, corosync

I need to set up a VIP with pcs in a 2 CentOS 7 node cluster. The resoruce gets defined like that:

```
pcs resource create MyVip ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=10.215.208.164/24  cidr_netmask=24 nic=ens32 op monitor interval=3s
```

This same config is working well in all other deployments. I just can't understand what the error means:

```
Failed Actions:
* MyVip_start_0 on node02 'not configured' (6): call=6, status=complete, exitreason='[findif] failed',
    last-rc-change='Fri Dec 28 20:47:26 2018', queued=0ms, exec=58ms
```

This is the interface thats seems not found:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens32: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:92:e2:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.215.208.173/24 brd 10.215.208.255 scope global noprefixroute ens32
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe92:e2f9/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting

- vip_start_0 on serv1.XXX.com 'unknown error' (1): call=6, status=complete, exitreason='[findif] failed',
  last-rc-change='Sat Sep 19 16:16:19 2020', queued=1ms, exec=159ms

Check if you have NIC setup for the resource:

```
pcs config
```

And check in response whether NIC is defined:

```
Cluster Name: VIP
        Corosync Nodes:
         serv1.centos7g.com serv2.XXX.com
        Pacemaker Nodes:
         serv1.centos7g.com serv2.XXX.com
    
    Resources:
     Resource: vip (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=IPaddr2)
      Attributes: cidr_netmask=24 ip=192.168.119.200 nic=YOUR_NIC_HERE
```

You can update nic for an existing resource. Worked for me (CentOS 7.2)

```
    pcs resource update RESOURCE_NAME nic=NIC_NAME
    pcs resource cleanup
    # check if IP address was created on your NIC interface
    ip a s  
    pcs status
```

Answer (score 0):

pcs resource create MyVip ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=10.215.208.164/24  cidr_netmask=24 nic=ens32 op monitor interval=3s

ip not to have cidr mask.

Correct defnitionw will be ::

ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=10.215.208.164  cidr_netmask=24 nic=ens32 op monitor interval=3s

Answer (score 0):

Got this error message with command

```
pcs resource create ClusterIP ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=1.2.3.4 cidr_netmask=32 op monitor interval=30s
```

I guess script `findif` tries to find an interface with appropriate network address for given ip. I have no any similar, so specifying an ip from my interfaces subnets solves the problem:

```
pcs resource create ClusterIP ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=192.168.243.123 cidr_netmask=32 op monitor interval=30s
```

Specifying interface manually also solves the problem:

```
pcs resource create ClusterIP ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=1.2.3.4 cidr_netmask=32 nic=lo op monitor interval=30s
```